# Node.js Express app only works via localhost, does not work over network (File or Directory not found)?

Tags: node.js, express, networking, localhost, iisnode

I am trying to create a node.js express app that is supposed to sit on an IIS server and be hit over the internet. However, I have only been able thus far to get this working via localhost. My node.js app works when accessing it via localhost on both my local machine and through IIS on a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine, but attempting to access via a URL or IP returns with the following page:

[image]

I am not sure exactly what is going on but I have been banging my head over this for the past day. If someone has any idea and could shed some light on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my app.js (.env file does not contain variables for PORT or IP and is only used for keys)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = require('./routes/index.js');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(router);

var port = process.env.PORT;
var ip = process.env.IP;

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on ${process.env.IP}:${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

index.js for routing

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var sfdcSystemController = require('../controllers/Salesforce/SystemController.js');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var fs = require('fs');

router.get('/',sfdcSystemController.doGet);

module.exports = router;
```

web.config for iisnode

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="nodejs">
          <match url="api/*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/app.js" />
          </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite> 
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <add segment="node_modules" />
          <add segment="iisnode" />
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This seems more like a networking problem, and the request never reaches your node.js server.

Comment: Found the problem, was actually an IIS problem. Answer is below.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my problem. Turns out it was more of a problem with IIS and how it was configured on the server vs what my code was doing.

In IIS, I had to do the following to get my node.js app working...

1. Update Anonymous Authentication, make sure it was enabled, and to give my App Pool Identity access to it instead of a server user.
2. Update Error Page Feature Settings to "Detail Errors"
3. Give my new node.js app its own IP instead of requiring a host header.